# Vertica SQL insert multiple rows in one statement

Tags: sql, vertica

Was wondering whether it's possible to accomplish the following in one insert statement?

```
drop table analytics.bw_covariance_matrix;
create table analytics.bw_covariance_matrix (
row int,
x1 float,
x2 float,
x3 float
);

insert into analytics.bw_covariance_matrix VALUES
(1, 4.01926965, -0.4686067, -0.07592112),
insert into analytics.bw_covariance_matrix VALUES
(2, -0.46860675,  4.1799267, -0.82461139);
insert into analytics.bw_covariance_matrix VALUES
(3, -0.07592112, -0.8246114,  4.37186211);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could `UNION` a SELECT to have a single `INSERT` statement:

```
insert into analytics.bw_covariance_matrix 
SELECT 1, 4.01926965, -0.4686067, -0.07592112
UNION
SELECT 2, -0.46860675,  4.1799267, -0.82461139
UNION
SELECT 3, -0.07592112, -0.8246114,  4.37186211
```

I don't believe that Vertica has a multi record insert statement like MySQL and other RDBMS's, so this is the best bet.

Comment: Not that it matters for this number of rows, but UNION ALL would be faster, since you're in control of the rows and don't need to distinct.

Answer (score 3):

```
insert into analytics.bw_covariance_matrix VALUES
(1, 4.01926965, -0.4686067, -0.07592112),
(2, -0.46860675,  4.1799267, -0.82461139),
(3, -0.07592112, -0.8246114,  4.37186211);
```

Try this instead:

```
INSERT INTO analytics.bw_covariance_matrix 
SELECT row, x1, x2, x3
FROM analytics.bw_covariance_matrix
WHERE row IN (1,2,3)
```

Comment: Does this work in Vertica. It's my understanding that Vertica doesn't support multi record insert.

Comment: ah .sorry missed it was for Vertica. No it won't work you will need to union the values instead.

Comment: Is the first column an ID column? if so you could just do:

    INSERT INTO analytics.bw_covariance_matrix
    SELECT row, x1, x2, x3
    FROM analytics.bw_covariance_matrix
    WHERE row IN (1,2,3)